# Shouldn't 'antilogarithm' be called 'logarithm'?

Tags: terminology, math-history

$$\log_ab=c$$

1. logos = ratio, referring to *a*;
2. arithmos = number, referring to *b*;

   therefore
3. logarithm = number (arithmos, *b*) to be expressed in terms of a ratio (logos, *a*).

So the logarithm itself is *b*, while *c* is the index to the logarithm generated from the logos/base *a*.

However it's common to speak as if *c* is the logarithm (as in "the logarithm of 100 to base 10 is 2") and *b* the antilogarithm. Isn't that confusing?

Comment: I may have found the answer. If 'logarithm' instead means 'number/arithmos indexing a position in a geometric sequence (sequence generated by a logos)' then it could refer naturally to *c*.

Comment: It’s often confusing to reason from word origins.

Comment: From the [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/l.html): According to the OED, "Napier does not explain his view of the literal meaning of *logarithmus*. It is commonly taken to mean 'ratio-number', and as thus interpreted it is not inappropriate, though its fitness is not obvious without explanation. Perhaps, however, Napier may have used *logos* merely in the sense of 'reckoning', 'calculation.'"

Comment: We have two numbers, $b$ and $c$, of which one is expressed by the other in terms of a ratio. So is the "logarithm" the one being expressed or the one doing the expressing? Each number is a function of the other; it seems an arbitrary choice. If indeed Napier had one of these reasons in mind for using the word _logarithm,_ apparently he used that word for the function that he found more useful at the time.

Comment: To show what @Lubin means, autism means belief or practicing oneself literally. It got it's name, when it was thought part of schizophrenia meaning cleft mind. but technically if you look anti + logarithm up in wikitionary, you'll get it as to act against reason about numbers.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee 'Autism' means 'selfism', no? From Greek *autos* meaning *oneself*.

Comment: @Blue I like the reference, though I'm unsatisfied with the OED's reasoning.

Comment: @DavidK To my mind the significance is whether the way we talk about logarithms makes natural sense. If 2 is the logarithm to base 10 of 100, then 2 is the logarithm, not 100. I'm now reconciled to the view that this way of speaking is correct, with the logarithm / *arithmos* being the index *c*, which is the 'ratio number' indexing the position of *b* in the geometric sequence whose *logos* / ratio is *a*.

Comment: The "index" or "ratio number" interpretation seems to be supported by at least one history-of-math publication: https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/logarithms-the-early-history-of-a-familiar-function-john-napier-introduces-logarithms

Comment: -ism means a practice of belief system or a pathology. @mcd

Comment: Among the many interpretations of the word *logos* in my little Classical-Greek dictionary, “ratio” does not appear. “Computation” does, however. I have always thought that the word simply meant a method for dealing with numbers.

Comment: @mjc Your $question$ (confusion) appears to have been phrased in the last two sentences of the original post. If this is true, then the first three points are irrelevant and, hopefully, I have answered the $question$.

Comment: @Lubin 'ratio' is a standard way of translating 'λόγος' from Euclid. Since Euclid is central to the European mathematical renaissance, I think that's a highly relevant translation. For instance, https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Euclid/Elements.pdf p130 Def. 3: "**Λόγος** ἐστὶ δύο μεγεθῶν ὁμογενῶν ἡ κατὰ πηλικότητά ποια σχέσις." "A **ratio** is a certain type of condition with respect to size of two magnitudes of the same kind."

Comment: @poetasis My confusion and the motivation for my question was not "How are these terms used now?" but "How can I align the way these terms are used now with their derivation so that it all makes natural sense?". I do feel my question is answered, as I wrote above to DavidK.

Comment: @mjc  I liked DavidK's comment too. I upvoted it and your reply to his comment. I'm glad you got what you needed here.

Comment: Thanks, @mjc, for the illumination. Completely invalidates my old “understanding”.

Comment: @Lubin Very glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_ab=c$$

I'm now of the view that the normal way of speaking ("the logarithm of 100 to base 10 is 2") is correct, with the logarithm itself being *c*, the 'ratio-number' which indexes the position of *b* in the geometric sequence whose ratio (and, since Briggs, also base) is *a*.

Others suggest that "reckoning number" is the true derivation. I think the two derivations are compatible, and I find the "ratio-number" derivation more useful for understanding the past and present function. If anyone can quote Napier on this point, I'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks to all who answered and commented.

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

See Brian Rice & Enrique González-Velasco & Alexander Corrigan, [The Life and Works of John Napier (2017, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=zdJNDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), page 404-5, for the original context of Napier's discovery (please, note the kinematic model) :

> > Let the line $TS$ be *radius*, and $dS$ a given [arbitrary] *sine* in the same line: let $g$ move geometrically from $T$ to $d$ in certain determinate moments of time.[...]
>
> Thus if the line $bi$ is as described above, if $dS$ is an arbitrary sine —possibly
>   a whole number chosen from a published table— if the points $g$ and $a$ start
>   their motions with identical initial velocities, and if $a$ arrives at $c$ in the same
>   amount of time as $g$ arrives at $d$, the distance $bc$ —not necessarily an integer
>   in this general case— represents what we could call the *generating exponent* of the sine $dS$.
>
> Actually, Napier did not use the word logarithm in the *Constructio*. He called the distance $bc$ the “artificial number” of the sine $dS$. It must have been
>   later, when he was ready to publish the *Descriptio*, that he introduced the word
>   now in use. He may have realised that, for instance, $4S$ is obtained from $TS$ after four multiplications by the ratio $0.9999999$, in the case of the first table.
>   Thus, the artificial number of $4S$ is $4$, the number of ratios needed to obtain this
>   sine from the whole sine. Using the Greek words *logon* = ratio and *arithmos* = number, he concocted the word *logarithm* or number of ratios. This is the prevailing theory, but it has also been argued that Napier took the word logarithm directly from the The *Sand-Reckoner* of Archimedes. Regardless of its origins, “logarithm” was the word used instead of “artificial number” in the first translation of the *Constructio*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRAZA I don't really see the irrationality in naming here. For $\log_ab=c$, the logarithm *c* is the 'ratio-number' which indexes the position of *b* in the geometric sequence whose common ratio is *a*. I don't see what's incompatible with that in the paper you cite.

Comment: Since posting the question I have come round to the view that, as you say and as I've written in various comments here, it fits both modern usage and rational derivation to say that *c* is the logarithm of *b*. I don't think that is at all arbitrary; rather I think it follows very naturally from the derivation I just described, which seems to agree with you citation.

Answer (score -1):

You got the references all mixed up. The *logos* refers to $c,$ and the *arithmos* refers to $b.$

Comment: *arithmos* referring to *b* was in my OP, though I now think *c* is the better candidate. I don't see how *logos* can refer to *c*; *a* is clearly the ratio.

Comment: @Allawonder I disagree. The jury is still out on what logos and arithmos refer to but neither of these two words are relevant to this question. Only the combined final word [logarithm] matters. C is the [base A] logarithm of B  and B is the [base A] antilogarithm of C.

Comment: @poetasis You cannot disagree with History. Read about the invention of logarithms by Napier, and why he chose those names. Note that Napier wasn't thinking of the logarithms as exponents at all (Euler started that). To Napier the logarithms allowed you to reckon (calculate, reason) easily with (large) numbers. Arithmos in Greek. Thus, it's the logarithm that the logos refers to the arithmos is the so-called antilogarithm. I only didn't mention all that because it was irrelevant to confusing the names, which was what I wanted to set right.

Comment: @mjc No, $a$ is not any ratio. Ratio of what? Napier did not even think of generalised bases. He fixed a certain basis (related to the natural base $e$) and used his transformation to turn numbers into their logarithms, which he wasn't really thinking of as exponents. Euler brought the exponential definition. Thus, for Napier, the logarithms of numbers allowed you to easily reckon (reason) with these numbers. This was why they were originally invented. Thus, it's the logarithms that the *logos* refers to; the *arithmos* to the so-called antilogarithms.

Comment: Both of you: I'm not disagreeing with history or arguing what logo and arithmos refer to. I'm saying that they are not the $question$ here. My answer is a correction to the statement "So the logarithm itself is b, while c is the index to the logarithm..." that was in the question. B is not the logarithm. C is the logarithm and B is the antilogarithm.

Comment: @poetasis I really don't know what you're talking about here again. OP asked precisely about confusion of those terms, and I think you're misreading. I have no energy for this.

Comment: @Allawonder *a* is the ratio between terms in the geometric sequence in which *c* indexes the position of *b*. Napier implicitly distinguishes between base and ratio in his work, taking a base of $10^7$ and a fractional ratio such that higher values of *c* give lower values of *b*. Briggs later suggested making the base and ratio equal. To me it's quite clear that ratio is central to the original and present logarithm, and at present I find this derivation more satisfying than the "reckoning-number" derivation, but I will have a think about the latter.

Comment: On reflection, I think the 'ratio-number' and 'reckoning-number' interpretations are not mutually exclusive; however, I find 'ratio-number' far more useful for understanding the structure of the function. If anyone can quote a passage from Napier where he addresses this, I'd be interested to see.

Comment: @mjc I'm really running out of energy here. But suffice it to say Napier wasn't thinking of geometric series. He defined his system for all positive real numbers, using the language of motion. Today we would write this as an IVP.

Comment: @Allawonder Don't feel obliged to continue if you don't want to. As far as I can see the central idea of Napier's *Mirifici logarithmorum canonis descriptio* (http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/napier/ademonstratiobookone.pdf) is the linking of an arithmetic sequence (the index *c*) to a geometric one (with common ratio *a*). That's the significance of the diagrams with which he introduces the book. The *constructio* (https://archive.org/details/constructionofwo00napiuoft/page/n1) is packed with references to geometric sequences. It seems fairly open-and-shut to me.